# How to use memo on custom react hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

From react docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) I used hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const FriendStatus = (props) => {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }
    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });
  if (isOnline === null) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }
  return isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
};
```

How to wrap `FriendStatus` using some `memo` to prevent recalculating (in react form of components prerendering)?

```js
export default memo(FriendStatus);
```

Throwing typescript errors.

Comment: `FriendStatus` is not a "custom hook". It's just a functional component. Also if there are typescript errors it's better to add them to the question.

Comment: Are you sure? Why is there big heading "custom hook" in react docs?

Comment: it was original component from which we are going to extract some logic into custom hook. Next section contains custom hook `useFriendStatus` - that's a custom hook.